# Donsker class and law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $P$ be a probability measure on a measurable space $(E, \mathcal {E})$, and let
$\mathcal {F}$ be a countable collection of measurable functions $f : E \to \mathbb {R}$
which is a Donsker class for $P$ in the sense that if $X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$
are independent random variables with common distribution $P$, the sequence
$(\frac {1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n [f(X_i) - E(f(X_i))])_{n \geq 1}$
is uniformly tight over $\mathcal {F}$ and the finite dimensional distributions
converge to a (centered) Gaussian process indexed by $\mathcal {F}$.
Is it then also true that there is a uniform law of the iterated logarithm, that is
$$
    \sup_{n} \sup_{f \in \mathcal {F}} 
        \frac {1}{\sqrt {2 n \ln \ln n}} \bigg | \sum_{i=1}^n [f(X_i) - E(f(X_i))] \bigg | < \infty
$$
almost surely?

Answer (score 1):

For such a Donsker class $\mathcal {F}$,
the necessary and sufficient condition for the uniform law of the iterated logarithm
to hold true is that $E(Z^2/\ln \ln (Z)) < \infty$ where
$Z =  \sup_{f \in \mathcal {F}} [f(X_1) - E(f(X_1))]$. This is standard material which may be
found in the Ledoux-Talagrand 1991 book.